# How do I resolve the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined of my Global varible?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table

I copied an pasted the below code in my chrome browser console. The code is supposed to dynamically generate a table and fill it with the contents found in an array.

Thought my code looks valid, I keep getting the error message below:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at :15:31*

Find below my code:

```
var array = [["A1", "B1", "C1"],
        ["A2", "B2", "C2"],
        ["A3", "B3", "C3"],
        ["A4", "B4", "C4"],
        ["A5", "B5", "C5"],
        ["A6", "B6", "C6"],
        ["A7", "B7", "C7"]],

table = document.getElementById("table");

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++);
{
   //=== Adds a new Row
   var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);

   for(var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++);
   {
       //=== Adds a new cell
       var cell = newRow.InsertCell(j)  ;

       //=== Adds value to the cell
       cell.innerHTML = array[i][j];
   }
}
```

When I click on the: *15:31* in the error message, it suggests that the `array[i].length` inside the second `for(var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++);` loop is the issue.

My personal experiences with these types of **error messages** is that the variable in subject usually isn't globally defined. My code, however indicates that the `array` variable is globally defined.

Can someone kindly explain why my globally defined `array` isn't recognised as already defined and perhaps give me a solution?

Comment: you are actually trying to get `length` property of an undefined variable. you have a `;` in the end of your for which just iterate your array and then run bracket block scope with i = array.lenght + 1. your `for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++);` should be `for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)`, without `;`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have made a couple of mistakes.

1. You have put semicolons right after the two for statements.

   for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++);

   for(var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++);
2. You have mistyped the **insertCell** function to **InsertCell**.

   var cell = newRow.InsertCell(j)  ;

Remove the semicolons and change the function name and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Watch for your semicolumns. See:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
  console.log(i);
}
```

When you put a semicolumn in end of `for` sentence, you are actually creating a `for` without body and a blocked scoped:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++); // it will just increment i until i >= array.length
{
  console.log(i); // 4
  // if you array[i] will get undefined, that's what you getting
  // undefined.length will throw an error
}
```